# PyQt/PySide: Dynamicly Find Item on ComboBox

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I've set the completer to `PopupCompletion` it works but only for character from the first text (to end). I have tried `UnfilteredPopupCompletion` it's just shows all item inside `QComboBox()` instead: when inputting characters from the end of string or middle. I want it Dynamic, can be searched from character of the first, mid, and end words.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("QListView::item {height:30px;}")
        self.comboBox.setView(QtWidgets.QListView())
        json_content = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]
        for element in json_content:
            self.comboBox.addItem(QtGui.QIcon('./img/waku/waku_choco_berry_loop.jpg'), element)
        self.comboBox.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 10))
        self.comboBox.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.comboBox.setEditable(True)
        self.comboBox.setInsertPolicy(QtWidgets.QComboBox.NoInsert)
        self.comboBox.completer().setCompletionMode(QtWidgets.QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = MainWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm thinking to use regex instead (`re`) and connecting it to the completer, but, doing a literal search requires list of string which I don't have; since I straightly put the Item into `QComboBox()`

Do note: that the program is procedurally generate Content from a JSon Config that can has 100+ items, thus, I also think that: serving much of string into both `QComboBox` and a list is memory consuming; when can I just find it directly on the combo-box.

Comment: A 100 string list isn't that memory consuming. Even with more than 10 thousands items with 10 letters each you'll still probably get far less than one megabyte. Considering that the basic Qt modules you need for an UI (QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets) take no less than 35mB alone, worrying about a list of 100 strings is quite pointless. Besides, I don't know what you mean by "use regex instead and connecting it to the completer": QCompleter already support matching the "middle" of the strings by setting the correct match flag for its [`filterMode`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#filterMode-prop).

Comment: Now that, you mention it. I thought i had to set custom model. Thanks again @musicamante

Comment: You don't need to set a custom model: just set the completer with the combobox `model()`. Note that it seems that there's an unsolved problem about that: by default, QCompleter uses `PopupCompletion` mode, but since there already exist a popup (that of the combobox), it will probably never show up; setting the mode to `InlineCompletion` will still be insufficient though, because the key event will take precedence and the resulting completion might not the expected one (for instance, typing `w` will show `wwo` in your case, with the final `wo` being selected). I'll dig more into that.